# change color according to class with SASS condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, colors, sass, background-color

I am creating cards and I want them to have different color according to their type (angel, demon, etc.) The type is a condition in my JS file according to my database. 
I am using SASS and I'm lost ! 
I tried something like this but it doesn't work at all, any idea ?

```
 .card{
        @if .demon{
            background-color: yellowgreen;
        }
        @if .angel{
            background-color: aqua;
        }
}
```

I want the all card to change not just where the type appear,

Any help is welcomed thanks in advance !

Comment: Not quite sure if that was the question but you might just remove those `@if` before classes demon and angel?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Nao,

Supposing we have a flag comming from the API called `cssClass: string` string is the `angel` or `demon` value which came from the API.

then, in our class, at the `render` method, we can get the `cssClass` value after we have stored it in the class's `state` as follows:

`const { cssClass } = this.state`

supposing we have a `Card` component that will be rendered when that value changes, we can do this to listen to the cssClass value changes and give a proper `className` depending on it.
In `render` method we have this:

```
render(){
  const { cssClass } = this.state;
  return(
    <Card className={`card ${cssClass.length ? cssClass : ''}} />
  )
}
```

In here: `className={`card ${cssClass.length ? cssClass : ''}}`

we are asking the `cssClass` attribute if it holds any length of a string that is greater than `0` as a value, if `true`, return that value, which could be `demon` or `angel`, else, it will return an empty string.

in your css file you'll not need any `@if` flags, just do the css regularly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parent selector:

```
.card{
            .demon &{
                background-color: yellowgreen;
            }
            .angel &{
                background-color: aqua;
            }
    }
```